# Augmented Reality Using GPS Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, gps, augmented-reality

I am working on Augmented reality . I am using Vuforia SDK. 
Sample project of scanning target is working fine.

But i want to do like based on GPS coordinates i want to locate 3d model on earth surface i mean when i reach to that place i can see that 3d model just like on earth surface.

But i want to know which SDk or tool i can use to implement this Using unity.

If someone is having knowledge - idea about this then please help me out.

Thanks.

Reference link : [Demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C5_xjDbrbR4)

Answer (score 2):

Qualcomm have another product called Gimbal, which combines Vuforia with location-awareness (using geofences, or beacons).

http://www.gimbal.com/

Comment: But Its not for unity.

Comment: Oh true you are right. When I used Gimbal v1 originally I wrote a iOS plugin to access it from Unity. Forgot about that.

Comment: hmm but thanks @peterept

Comment: So in respect then to your original question, in Unity you can access the GPS via it's location service. However, it's accuracy could be out 100m (especially if the user is not in a moving). But you could show the object and track with the gyro.

Answer (score 0):

Using Unity Wikitude is better for location applications and games.

Check Below link:

http://www.wikitude.com/blog-build-pokemon-go-app/

But Compared to Vuforia it's costly..

Thanks,

AdisheshuReddy.